# How to server static files in the folder without folder 'static'? Django

Tags: django, static

I have my index.html and static files in this structure:

- templates:

  - folder:

    - index.html
    - css
    - js
    - images
  - another_folder:

    - index.html
    - css
    - js
    - images

I want that staticfiles finder will look for static in templates by domain name in request. Please, without 'static' folder and {% load static %} tag. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by domain name? And also I didn't understand why there are 2 folders in templates dir and each with a separate index.html?

Comment: @Sunlight I have several proxy servers that will receive site source from main server, where located django and those folders with index.html and another static. For example, if domain is "site.domain.com"(configured in nginx on proxy server), then folder will name "site.domain.com"(for easier search static in this folder). I don't need jinja in my html, just raw HTML code. Should i write custom staticfiles finder?

Comment: You can try making a django route for `/*` and append it at the end of the `urls` list. And in the view for that route get the PATH, read the file from that PATH and send response back to that.

Comment: @Sunlight Seems that function not calling. I have warning(already tried to delete trailing / or add url like `test/*`) "(urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/*' has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'." And i also have error "Not Found: /test/img/pin-online.png"(i am testing on local machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I am found a solution. Here is url for static: `re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', static, {'document_root': 'templates/lands/'}),`
Here is my view:

```
def static(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    domain = request.get_host()
    path = domain + '/' + posixpath.normpath(path).lstrip('/')
    fullpath = safe_join(document_root, path) 
    statobj = os.stat(fullpath)
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
    content_type = content_type or 'application/octet-stream'
    response = FileResponse(open(fullpath, 'rb'), content_type=content_type)
    response["Last-Modified"] = http_date(statobj.st_mtime)
    if stat.S_ISREG(statobj.st_mode):
        response["Content-Length"] = statobj.st_size
    if encoding:
        response["Content-Encoding"] = encoding
    return response
```